# How to build all for push and certain path for pull_requests?

Tags: github-actions

I would like to trigger a build on the entire code base for a push, but only trigger certain paths for a pull request. How can I do it in github actions. I tried the following but it doesn't seem to build for the push:

```
name: Build Backend

on:
  push:
    paths: ./**
  pull_request:
    paths: 
      - components/backend/**
      - .github/workflows/**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default will trigger for all paths, so you can just not specify any path for `push`.

```
name: Build Backend

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    paths: 
      - components/backend/**
      - .github/workflows/**
```